# Orientdb property name size with hybrid-schema

Tags: orientdb

I know that in schema less mode property names have to be saved along property values, therefore the shorter name the better.

How does it work with partial schema? Are only schemaless properties saved with property names?

What is default schema type? Do I have to remember to set strictmode after each class declaration to save space?

Comment: You can find some information here: https://orientdb.com/docs/last/Schema.html

Comment: Thats the document that make me ask this question, yes.